# GREP values from a column in txt file

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a txt file with 1200 entries in this way (iPerf output by the way)

```
1  [  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  10.6 MBytes  89.1 Mbits/sec
2  [  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  13.5 MBytes   113 Mbits/sec
3  [  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  9.50 MBytes  79.7 Mbits/sec
4  [  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  9.00 MBytes  75.5 Mbits/sec
```

How can I get **ONLY** the second values expressed in Mbits/sec using grep ?

Output example:

```
89.1
113
79.7
75.5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $9}' your-file.txt
```

will do it for you. For example:

```
$ cat ~/test.txt
1  [  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  10.6 MBytes  89.1 Mbits/sec
2  [  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  13.5 MBytes   113 Mbits/sec
3  [  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  9.50 MBytes  79.7 Mbits/sec
4  [  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  9.00 MBytes  75.5 Mbits/sec

$ awk '{print $9}' ~/test.txt
89.1
113
79.7
75.5
```

Another way to tackle this is:

```
 awk -F 'MBytes' '{print $2}' test.txt | awk -F 'Mbits' '{print $1}' | tr -d " "
```

In the above method we are:

- Splitting each line by MBytes.
- That gives us 2 parts: $1 is everything before MBytes. $2 is everything after MBytes
- We choose everything after MBytes and split it further by Mbits
- That gives us two parts again and we choose everything before Mbits
- If there is white space before and after the numbers, we use `tr` to remove white space

So we get

```
$ cat test.txt
1  [  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  10.6 MBytes  89.1 Mbits/sec
2  [  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  13.5 MBytes   113 Mbits/sec
3  [  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  9.50   MBytes  79.7 Mbits/sec
4  [  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  9.00 MBytes    75.5 Mbits/sec

awk -F 'MBytes' '{print $2}' test.txt | awk -F 'Mbits' '{print $1}' | tr -d " "

Result:
89.1
113
79.7
75.5
```

Comment: It works! I changed the value from 9 to 7 and i got the values. However a now "problem" is raised. The spaces are not the same amongst all rows. i.e[  4]  8.0- 9.0 sec  6.88 MBytes  57.7 Mbits/sec
[  4]  9.0-10.0 sec  7.25 MBytes  60.8 Mbits/sec
[  4] 10.0-11.0 sec  8.25 MBytes  69.2 Mbits/sec
[  4] 11.0-12.0 sec  8.75 MBytes  73.4 Mbits/sec
[  4] 12.0-13.0 sec  12.4 MBytes   104 Mbits/sec

There is any way to remove the spaces or put the smae space from each value? (i.e 1 space)

Thbaks

Comment: Added an example with `awk` and `tr` that may also help.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is fixed length format you can always use `cut`

```
cut -c38-41 data
```

if you know that the values are 4 chars wide.